# Display an image in browser from data url with node/angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm using [node-captcha](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-captcha) to generate captchas as data URLs. I want to display the resulting PNG image in the browser. My captcha generator looks like this, pretty much identical to the example in the link to node-captcha:

```
exports.getChallenge = function(req, res) {
  captcha({ fileMode: 0 }, function(text, data) {
    res.send(data);
  });
};
```

I have that function routed to /api/challenge, and an angular controller that retrieves this challenge:

```
app.factory('Challenge', ['$resource',  function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/challenge');
}]);

app.controller('challengeController', ['$scope', 'Challenge', function($scope, Challenge) {
  $scope.initChallenge = function() {
    Challenge.get( function(res) {
      $scope.captchaImage = res;
    });
  };
}]);
```

Now, in my actual HTML file, I have this:

```
<div data-ng-controller="challengeController" data-ng-init="initChallenge()">
  <img ng-src="{{captchaImage}}"></img>
</div>
```

However, the image doesn't load. You only see the little broken image icon that appears whenever an image doesn't load. How can I make a captcha display as an image?

Comment: What is inside `$scope.captchaImage` ? Can you post the contents of this variable ?

Comment: Try flushing `{{captchaImage}}` into `src`, not `ng-src`. If `captchaImage` contains a data URL, as you say, then it should be sufficient to put that into `img[src]` directly.